# Binding Linq expression to a Xaml control property with MVVM

Tags: wpf, linq, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am writing a WPF application, In my view I need to show a dashboard of the Employee attendance count grouped based on different properties of Employee class. I will just have a observable Collection of Employee objects which will keep getting updated which should in turn update the counters in the dashboard.

Because of the dynamic nature of the Properties on which the count needs to group by, We cannot use as many properties as the no of counters we need to show.

So Can anyone please help if there is a way to bind a linq expression to a property which evaluate and update the view every time there is some change in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to roll this yourself in your viewmodel.

Give the `ObservableCollection<Employee>` a `CollectionChanged` handler. In that handler, you want to give each newly added `Employee` a `PropertyChanged` handler, and remove that `PropertyChanged` handler from any `Employee` that is removed from the collection. So two handlers:

```
void Employees_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)

void Employee_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
```

Now you've got a notification any time the collection gets or loses an item, and another notification any time a property of an item *in* the collection changes its value.

Now write a method that updates your aggregates, groups, whatever. Call it `UpdateCounters()`. `UpdateCounters()` does LINQ stuff and puts the results in viewmodel properties with private setters. Call `UpdateCounters()` in the collection's CollectionChanged handler, and in the Employees' PropertyChanged handler. If you only care about some of the properties of Employee, save some cycles by having `Employee_PropertyChanged` only call `UpdateCounters()` when the appropriate properties change.

Comment: Thanks,only problem with this is,i will not able to define props in viewmodel bcoz no of counters is dynamic based on emp attribs..let's say there are emps belonging to 3 divisions of the company I need 3 counters and after that if there are 4 different designations they belong to, I need 3*4 =12 counters for each designation division combination. For this I would need to get the counters repeated using items control and so I wouldn't be able to define prop for each counter in the vm and o trying to see if I can bind a long exp in the xaml for each counter

Comment: @KNara So put the results of the expressions in an ObservableCollection and display in an ItemsControl. That sounds fine to me. You can't put LINQ in a binding, and if you could, that would be less flexible anyway.

Comment: In that case how can I update any change or how can I raise.propertychanged. I would not know which property item of the counters collection needs to be updated . I am not liking the idea of having if conditions to update that particular property as I need to show counters on 4 attribute combinations so basically am thinking if I could bind an expression for each counter, I would raise propertychange event for all counters and they' would reevaluate the exp themselves to update new value.... Please correct me if am understanding it the wrong way

Comment: The counter result objects should raise PropertyChanged if their values change. You CANNOT BIND AN EXPRESSION. Bedtime here. We'll get this figured out in the (my) morning. It's not a hard problem at all, don't sweat it.